# How to use specific link script(*.lds) with CMake?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cmake, ld

I'm trying to write a bare-metal program with CMake(my project is locate in https://github.com/oska874/cmake_test).
The demo source code are these:

my.c

```
void mymain(void)
{
    int a=0;
    a++;
    a++;
}
```

and link script file is :

my.lds

```
ENTRY(mymain)
SECTIONS
{   
   . = 0x10000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   . = 0x8000000;
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

I can compile it with command bellow:

```
gcc -c my.c
ld -T my.lds -o my my.o
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing with CMake for cmake always use its' own .lds script.

I tried search google and stackoverflow but all method failed.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

I have tried CMakeLists.txt as bellow:

```
PROJECT(FreeRtos)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG " -T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my.lds -static")

AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. MYSRC)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(my  ${MYSRC} )

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
```

And this

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT(LINKERSCRIPT C)
# dummy.c must exist:
ADD_EXECUTABLE(EXE my.c dummy.c)
# linkerscript must exist:
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(
        dummy.c PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my.lds
        )
```

I checked the `link.txt` in `CMakeFiles/EXE.dir/` ,it shows that :

```
 /usr/bin/cc  -g     -T /os_dev/workspace/test/ezio/tool/eo/freertos-pine64/Source/t2/my.lds -static CMakeFiles/my.dir/my.c.o  -o my -rdynamic
```

I tried to exchange cc with ld with command that:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/ld <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET>")
```

It works ,the link.txt shows CMake will use my.lds.

Comment: Just pass `-T my.lds` as **linker flags**, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077414/cmake-how-to-set-the-ldflags-in-cmakelists-txt.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Alreday tried but has no effect.

Comment: Then show the code (`CMakeLists.txt`) which have you tried.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've post one.

Comment: **The first approach**: Variable CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG is used only when build type is "Debug". You attempt to set defaul type, but do that *incorrectly* (you should set *cached* variable). See [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40482191/3440745) about proper way for set default build type. If you don't wont to bother with build type, just append flags to *CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS* variable: it is always used. **The second approach** just adds dependency from the given file, it doesn't treat this file as a linker script automatically.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you. After modify `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ` with your comment,link.txt can find the link script,but still have some question as showed ,1. CMake use cc instead of ld to linking, 2. how to remove the `-rdynamic`  option ?

Comment: As I see, you have already find the [proper way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25274328/3440745) for specifying the linker. As for removing `-rdynamic` option, it is easily googled: http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2009-October/032948.html. (Because you create executable, you need to modify *CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS* variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake has no special variable for ldscript, so you may resort to appending appropriate **linker flags**:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my.lds")
```

(This should be placed **after** `project()` call in `CMakeLists.txt`).

See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077414/cmake-how-to-set-the-ldflags-in-cmakelists-txt) for more information about setting linker flags in CMake.