# cmake force config=Release for library

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

I have a cmake c++ project which consists of several executables and dlls. Because the dlls get injected into another application, they have to be built with config=Release, even when the executables are built with debug info.

Is there any way to force cmake to do that? I tried `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")` right before the call to `add_library()`, but that didn't work.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: *Why* do the libraries have to be built in release mode? What do you mean by *injected*? *How* do you "inject" the libraries?

Comment: I am using [easyhook](https://easyhook.github.io/) to inject the dlls into another process. This fails if the dlls are built with config=Debug.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, when you build the library, you have to additionally specify the *config*

For example:

```
cmake --build {BUILDDIR} --config Release
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423820/10248910

Comment: Yes, I know that and I am passing that along. However I am building all the files with that single command. So if I build them with `cmake --build {BUILDDIR} --config Debug` I want the dlls to ignore the config parameter and build with `--config Release` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best but,

```
target_compile_options(libmylib PRIVATE "-O3")
```

gets the job done.

Comment: Would you kindly explain why this is not the best approach or why does this work, and why `-O3` is needed here?

Comment: 1. why this is not the best approach?
-> Might want to ideally pass CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE instead of just "-O3".
2. Why "O3"?
-> By release I assumed "optimized" in the above question. With "O3" most compilers (clang/gcc/msvc) will do optimized codegen.