# Build Release version of abseil-cpp static binary libs under Windows

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, abseil

I am using [abseil-cpp](https://abseil.io/) in my C++ project built under Visual Studio 2019 / Windows 10.

Using CMake (not Visual Studio built-in makefile support) and following the [static binaries](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/tools/cmake-installs) instructions I have built a set of libraries and header files which I can then successfully link into a standard Visual Studio solution.

The issue I have is that the library builds with a build type of `Debug`, which means that I cannot link them into a `Release` build of my application.

What I need is to build a `Release` version of the abseil-cpp libraries. However the for the life of me I cannot figure out how to coax CMake / Abseil build process to do this!

I have tried the following, all of which are either ignored or error:

- Add `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` to the CMakeLists.txt file in the root of the `abseil-cpp` source tree
- Add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` to the `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Source/CMakeProject/install` step given in the instructions
- Add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release to the cmake --build . --target install` step given in the instructions

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to build a Release version of static binary libraries?

Ian

Comment: Have you tried what it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423820/3987854)?

Comment: Yes that did it, thank you! I now have VS puking with an internal link error, so on to the next issue :)