# cmake build debug/release, Windows VS macOS

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cmake

Typical cmake produre here was:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg.cmake
cmake --build .
```

That worked on both Windows and macOS. But then I noticed it was building in debug mode.

To choose build mode on Windows I did

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg.cmake
cmake --build . --config=THEMODE
```

While on macOS I need to do

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=THEMODE
cmake --build .
```

Where THEMODE is either Debug/Release.

I bet I'm missing something, isn't? The Cmake is all about Multiplatform, why it works differently to choose build mode on Windows/macOS?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you're generating build files for a multi-configuration tool on Windows (e.g. Visual Studio) and a single-configuration tool on macOS (e.g. Makefile). That's why you need to specify:

- [`--config <cfg>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) on Windows
- and [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) on macOs.

Answer (score 1):

There are multi-config generators and others. "Others" need `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` provided explicitly per cmake configuration. Multi-config can be generated once and built in supported configurations. Visual Studio generator is a multi-config one but it isn't cross-platform. Ninja, on the other hand, is a multi-config generator and cross-platform.

So you generate and build it the same way on all platforms:

```
cmake -G "Ninja Multi-Config" ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

On Windows you need to run this command with VS setup in the terminal aka "Developer Terminal", otherwise there is no Ninja installed by default and MSVC compiler won't be found.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cool to have `--config` inferring its value from `DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`?

Comment: @KcFnMi config is an option for multi-config generators and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is for others. It would not make sense to infer one from the other. Anyway, all of these options will eventually go out of use and will be replaced with CMake presets.

Comment: @KcFnMi there is also [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024259/how-to-change-the-build-type-to-release-mode-in-cmake/19029864#19029864) which will allow you to use only  `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` everywhere and do not use the `--config` option at all. Many a righteous man don't like that solution, though. As you can clearly see by the score it has.